# How do I send a message and an embed in one message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am making a starboard command and I want it to look like this
[image]

I tried

```
message.channel.send("message" + embed) it didn't work
```

and I tried

```
message.channel.send("message")
message.channel.send(embed)
```

That just seperates the message into two

Could someone teach me how to do it? Or its just not doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you heard of commas before? I assume not.

```js
message.channel.send("message")
message.channel.send(embed)
```

This will split the message into two because you used .send() twice! All you have to do is use commas. Like this:

```js
message.channel.send("message", embed);
```

This will work!